# mysqldump error in exporting a table from a database

Tags: mysql, database, export

Can anyone please let me know why am I getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -p --user=root database_name utilities > utilities.sql'

on this `mysqldump -p --user=root database_name utilities > utilities.sql;`

I tried keeping the database name, table name in backticks. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: mysql -uXXX -pXXX < dump_file.sql  Doesn't look like you wrote it like it should..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) should be run from a normal command prompt/shell *instead* of the `mysql` command, not at the mysql prompt inside it.

```
ubuntu-vm:~$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 38
Server version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (Ubuntu)

mysql> exit
Bye

ubuntu-vm:~$ mysqldump -help
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
ic@ubuntu-vm:~$
```